# ASP.NET MVC 2 Localization/Globalization stored in the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, localization

I've been searching for a while for a good example of localizing an C# ASP.NET MVC 2 application but storing the data in the database instead of .RESX files.  Unfortunately I've had no luck finding a good example and was hoping someone else may know and could point me in the right direction?

Many thanks for any help/advice/articles

Answer (score 5):

Resource provider model:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx

Scroll down to the section titled Building a Database Resource Provider.

Answer (score 4):

I'd also recommend these links:

- [Localization model with database resource provider](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/29/extending-the-asp-net-2-0-localization-model-with-a-database-resource-provider.aspx)
- [MVC localization](http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC---Localization.aspx)
- [Related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044493/net-mvc-localization-resourceprovider-implementation-not-working-correctly)

Comment: Related links in the first link you mentioned are not exist.

Comment: @QMaster Not really within my control, but Google can still find the articles if you bother to search: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379546(VS.80).aspx