# ASP.Net MVC model translate language for display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, language-translation

I am working on multi-language enabled mvc application. I have a translation table in database, which I bring on application start and save it in application memory.

The database structure is {TextId, LanguageId, Translation}. TextId is assigned to each UI element (like label, validators, dropdown list text, etc.). There is an admin interface to manage the translation text.

I want to know what is a good way to show translated text on UI, and where is the best place to do the actual translation. I do not want to use the resource manager, since the database is being used in other Asp & Asp.Net webforms applications.

Here is the model (for example)

```
public class UserLoginModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="ER001")]
    [Range(6,10,ErrorMessage="ER002")]
    [Display(Description="TX001", Name="TX002")]
    public string LoginId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="ER003"), DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Language Id will be in Session["LanguageId"], and TranslationText is in Application variable.

Models reside in separate project, hence there is not direct access to session, but I can use DI (don't know whether it is a good practice!)

Here are following things I was considering:

1. Write Html helper extension like @Html.TranslateText("TX001"). I started with this method, but soon realized that @Html.ValidationMessage accepts only one message, irrespective of multiple validator attributes on property. I cannot use EditorFor templates either.
2. Use javascript to replace text ids with appropriate messages
3. Use reflection on model and replace text ids for attributes.

I am leaning towards option 3, by extending ModelMetadataProvider, or writing action filter attribute, or in EditorForModel template.

I am very confused on how to proceed. I am still in process of learning MVC. Hence. I would like to ask experts on how to handle this problem in best possible way.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 3 : - Using database instead of resource files as the localization store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562916/asp-net-mvc-3-using-database-instead-of-resource-files-as-the-localization-s)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was able to implement the functionality accordingly.