# Asp.net MVC - Resource file per customer (ignore cultures)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Same as the normal resources which is used for localization where you have Resources.resx + Resources.en-US.resx and so on, this is working based on the culture.

All my customers are in the same localization but i would like to programatically take the string from Resources.resx unless the string is in the customer's resource which can be named Resources.CUS1.resx. Then it will be using the more specific term.

Any idea? searched a lot for this yet nothing.

Comment: Resources and cultures are very heavily tied together, you'll probably have more luck rolling your own solution tbh.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562916/asp-net-mvc-3-using-database-instead-of-resource-files-as-the-localization-s) would be a good starting point